# Why 'kubectl get nodes' not working after xargs?

Tags: macos, kubectl, xargs

When i tried this in iterm2 (macOS), it works.

```
kubectl get nodes node1 node2 --show-labels
```

And when i tried this, it works.

```
echo "node1" | xargs -I{} kubectl get nodes {} --show-labels
```

But when i tried this, it didn't works.

```
echo "node1 node2" | xargs -I{} kubectl get nodes {} --show-labels
```

I think there is something problem with whitespace but i can't solve it.
Can you help me?

Comment: What should the end result be, here?

Answer (score 0):

By default, `xargs` will stuff as many of the arguments provided into a single command as possible. (I added `echo` to your original `xargs` invocation so we see what's happening.)

```
$ echo "node1 node2 node3 node4" | xargs -I{} echo kubectl get nodes {} --show-labels
kubectl get nodes node1 node2 node3 node4 --show-labels
```

If you'd like each selector to be a command of its own, you'll need to add `-n1`:

```
$ echo "node1 node2 node3 node4" | xargs -n1 -I{} echo kubectl get nodes {} --show-labels
kubectl get nodes node1 --show-labels
kubectl get nodes node2 --show-labels
kubectl get nodes node3 --show-labels
kubectl get nodes node4 --show-labels
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but kubectl provide multi search using space like 'kubectl get nodes node1 node2 --show-labels'  In this way, we can send request only once but -n1 request   4 times..

Comment: Yes, well what is your original problem then?

Comment: I solved it! Without xrags -I{} option, it works!
echo "node1 node2" | xargs kubectl get nodes --show-labels
It's really helpful when you want to know pod information and node information together.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it is not clear enough what you are trying to achieve with this solution - you can easily use solutions based on `kubectl` without need to touch `xargs`. However, if you were able to specify your real problem - maybe it would be easier to help you with the solution.

---

2 options you can use here:

- with xargs

  `echo node1,node2,node3,...nodeN | tr -d '\n' |  xargs -I{} -d "," kubectl get nodes {} --show-labels`
- without xargs

  `for node in $(kubectl get nodes -o name| cut -d "/" -f2); do kubectl get nodes $node --show-labels; done`

Comment: I solved it! Without xrags -I{} option, it works! echo "node1 node2" | xargs kubectl get nodes --show-labels It's really helpful when you want to know pod information and node information together.